# Video tag with controls attribute causing unit tests to fail

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, html5-video, karma-jasmine

I am building a webapp with Angular 7.2.4. I am using the default unit testing library that the angular CLI (7.3.1) comes with.

I keep running into this error as a failure when the unit tests run: 
`An error was thrown in afterAll\nResizeObserver loop limit exceeded thrown`

It seems that the `controls` attribute on one of the video inputs is causing this. If I remove the controls attribute all tests pass. I have no idea how to get around this as I need to use the video controls.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to resolve this without building a custom video player?

For reference here is the component (which is literally just a wrapper around the video player)

**video.component.html**

```
<video preload="auto"
       controls
       #videoPlayer
       controlsList="nodownload"
       (ended)="videoEnded($event)">
  <source [src]="getVideoSource()" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

**video.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import {ConfigService} from '../config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoPlayer: ElementRef;
  @Input() src: string;
  @Input() ended: (event: Event) => void;

  constructor(private cs: ConfigService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.src = this.getVideoSource();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.src = this.getVideoSource();
  }

  getVideoSource(): string {
    return this.cs.getConfig('videosUrl') + this.src;
  }

  videoEnded($event) {
    if (this.ended) {
      this.ended($event);
    }
  }

}
```

**video.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { VideoComponent } from './video.component';

describe('VideoComponent', () => {
  let component: VideoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VideoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ VideoComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VideoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.src = '';
    component.ended = () => {};
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

});
```

**UPDATE:** It would appear that this is a Chrome issue. This does not happen in firefox or safari

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I also created a wrapper component over video tag and my tests were failing with the same error, and the issue was also the 'controls' attribute.

I couldn't find the cause of it though.

I implemented a workaround for my tests where I overwritten the controller's template with TestBed.overrideComponent()

In you case it would be as follows:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { VideoComponent } from './video.component';

describe('VideoComponent', () => {
  let component: VideoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VideoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ VideoComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.overrideComponent(VideoComponent, {
      set: {
        template: `
          <video 
            preload="auto"
            #videoPlayer
            (ended)="videoEnded($event)">
            <source [src]="getVideoSource()" type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>`
      }
    }).createComponent(VideoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.src = '';
    component.ended = () => {};
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

});
```

Notice that there is no 'controls' attribute in the overwritten template.

It should be enough to unit tests the logic of your component.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue today with our CI's Chrome version, while it worked perfectly on dev computers.
Our solution: update Chrome on our CI (in this case, from 75 to 91).